# Change navigation theme color in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

The default Indigo color for GitLab doesn't suit my Header Logo. I want to change it to a lighter color. Are there any options to change the navigation theme color or can it changed programmatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The navigation theme color cannot be changed for everyone at once. It can only changed for individual profile.

As mentioned in [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html) document of Gitlab,

1. Click your avatar icon in the top right corner, select **Settings**
2. Choose **Preferences** from the left sidebar.
3. Select a color on **Navigation theme** and click **Save Changes**

Answer (score 7):

You can change the **default** theme (for new users) by setting

`gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_theme'] = THEME_NUMBER`

in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.  Afterwards run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.  See [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/43585) for the theme numbers.  E.g. `3` corresponds to the *Light* theme.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [GitLab 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#new-navigation-has-color-themes-available) (August 2023) proposes:

> ### New navigation has color themes available
>
> With the new navigation enabled, you can now select one of five different color themes, and choose the light or dark variety for each. Use themes to identify different environments or choose your favorite color.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_3/new-navigation-theming.png -- New navigation has color themes available]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#change-the-color-theme) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/378549).

So it is not *fully* customizable, but that is progress!